# Zoom in websites on android sdk emulator

Tags: android, browser, emulation, zooming, android-2.2-froyo

if I'm using the emulator of android-sdk and surfing to a website, how can I simulate the zooming I normally perform using two fingers? I couldn't find any shortcut or button to zoom in larger websites.

Thanks
Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you point your mouse to the browser window, press the left button and move a little, the zoom controls will appear in the stock Android browser and will let you zoom in and out.

Answer (score 11):

Browser zoom in: MENU + i

Browser zoom out: MENU + o

The "MENU" key is usually the key to the right of the right Windows key.

For more shortcuts, check this one out:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eyes-free/XpiX5wzrKKQ

Comment: What does "menu" mean? Is it a key? Also, the link is broken.

Comment: The "Menu" key is the key on the keyboard to the right of the right Windows key.

Answer (score 10):

Double-click then hold the second click and move the mouse up or down, works the same as doing a double-tap then sliding up or down with one finger on a device.

Answer (score 5):

You can also double-click on the screen of the emulator. That increases zoom, and if you then drag the screen the zoom controls appear.